# gettimeofday returns a negative value

Tags: c++, gettimeofday

I am writing a thread library, and when scheduling the threads I need to know how long they've been ready. Every Thread instance has a `timeval _timeInReady` field, and when I push an instance to the ready queue I call this function:

```
void Thread::startTiming() {
    gettimeofday(&_timeInReady, NULL);
}
```

When I want to check the current `_timeInReady` value I call:

```
double Thread::getTimeInReady() const {
    return TIME(_timeInReady.tv_sec,_timeInReady.tv_usec);
}
```

Where TIME is `#define TIME(a,b) ((a*1000000) + b)` So that I get the total time in microseconds.

My problem is that for some reason, I get crazy negative values (such as -10293843) when I check that field after a while.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What, precisely, do you observe that makes you think that you have negative numbers? If it is a print statement, please show it. If it is a debugger inspection, please tell us more about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should return the result as a 64-bit unsigned integer, as you want an integer microsecond result, not a fractional second (which would imply returning `double`):

```
unsigned long long Thread::getTimeInReady() const
{
    return (unsigned long long)_timeInReady.tv_sec * 1000000ULL +
        (unsigned long long)_timeInReady.tv_usec;
}
```

Your system might have `uint64_t` which is a more concise than `unsigned long long`, or you could `typedef` it.

Answer (score 1):

On my computer, all of `tv_sec`, `tv_usec`, and `1000000` are signed 32-bit quantities. Signed 32-bit values overflow when asked to hold a number bigger than 2^31 or so.

As a result, this expression:

```
((x.tv_sec*1000000) + x.tv_usec)
```

will overflow in `2^31 / 10^6` seconds, or about 2,147 seconds. As long as your program only deals in time intervals shorter than 35 minutes, you should be okay.

If you'd like to represent values >= 35 minutes, try replacing your `#define` with this:

```
#define TIME(a,b) ((a*1000000ull) + b)
```

Through the standard promotions, this change will cause all of your math to be performed with `unsigned long long` values.

You may, but need not, change your `double` to `uint64_t`. That's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for getting time for 32-bit systems :-

```
struct timeval time;
gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
unsigned long long secTime = ((unsigned long long)time.tv_sec) * 1000 + ((unsigned long long)(time.tv_usec))/1000;
```